# Itô's article "A measure-theoretic approach to Malliavin calculus"

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

Apart from citations all over the internet, the following paper appears to be off-the-grid.

- K. Itô, *A measure-theoretic approach to Malliavin calculus*, in 'New Trends in Stochastic Analysis', Proc. Taniguchi Symposium, Sept. 1994, Charingworth, (eds. K. D. Elworthy, S. Kusuoka and l. Shigekawa),
  World Scientific, 1997

Does there exist any electronic copy of the article? Or does anyone have a physical copy that they are comfortable with scanning/sharing?

Comment: I have a physical copy which I'd be happy to scan and send to you, but unfortunately I am away from my office for the next couple weeks.  If you have not managed to find a copy by Jan 15 or so, let me know.

Comment: You can find my website, with contact info, on my profile page, click here -->

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have scanned my copy and sent it to the OP.